# Get matched column value in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have a table strcture like this :

```
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
   ID | Scifi Name       |       Hospital Code       |     Layman Language    |
     1 | Hysoc           |       CBC                 |  torems
    2  | Loreim          |       HCI                 |   Loreims
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying match values while query like this :

```
"SELECT * FROM wp_vhh4zdnv0r_disease WHERE scifi_name like '%".$_GET['term']."%' OR hospital_code like '%".$_GET['term']."%' OR layman_language like '%".$_GET['term']."%'";
```

the query works fine but i am trying to get that field that matches values.like if `term ='cbc'` and `cbc` exist in `Hospital code` it returns only hospital code ? How i should achieve this.May be php code can help but i have no idea how to get that Thanks

Comment: put some dummy data, so that we can test ot make sqlfiddle

Comment: @PathikVejani check now the question.the search query may be values have cbc or lorem etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `case` statement like this:

```
$sql= "SELECT CASE WHEN scifi_name like '%".$_GET['term']."%' THEN scifi_name 
WHEN phospital_code like '%".$_GET['term']."%' THEN phospital_code
WHEN layman_language like '%".$_GET['term']."%' THEN layman_language 
END FROM wp_vhh4zdnv0r_disease";
```

Comment: so your condition doesn't consider

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION. Also don't forget to escape the user input with `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or similar function.

```
SELECT scifi_name FROM wp_vhh4zdnv0r_disease WHERE scifi_name like '%".$_GET['term']."%' UNION SELECT hospital_code FROM wp_vhh4zdnv0r_disease WHERE hospital_code like '%".$_GET['term']."%' UNION SELECT layman_language FROM wp_vhh4zdnv0r_disease WHERE layman_language like '%".$_GET['term']."%'"
```